# How to NOT execute javascript code on specific page

Tags: javascript

I have specific javascript code

```
   <script type="text/javascript" async="true" data-ad-type="iframe v2.0" charset="utf-8" src="//mydomaincom.com/generic/uni.php?g=5"></script>
```

that work on all pages, but on /ucp.php?mode=register I dont want to execute the code. How to do this?

I made this code but not working (two script inside?)

```
<script>
  if ( window.location.pathname == '/ucp.php?mode=register'{ 
     } else {
          <script type="text/javascript" async="true" data-ad-type="iframe v2.0" charset="utf-8" src="//sk.search.etargetnet.com/generic/uni.php?g=5"></script>
     }
</script>
```

The answer should be with PHP too, if with PHP i can make it.

Comment: It's not working because it's neither valid JS nor valid HTML.

Comment: Seen as your using PHP, why not control it from ServerSide?

Comment: So how can i do it with php? Can you send answer pls?

Comment: Any solution with php?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
if ( window.location.pathname != '/ucp.php'){ 
    var fileref=document.createElement('script')
            fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript")
            fileref.setAttribute("src","//sk.search.etargetnet.com/generic/uni.php?g=5")
    fileref.setAttribute("async","true")
    fileref.setAttribute("data-ad-type","iframe v2.0")
    fileref.setAttribute("charset","utf-8")

         }
```

Comment: Now not showing on all pages, not just on the specific.

Comment: `window.location.pathname` doesn't include the GET parameters

Comment: @LucaKiebel updated

Comment: Now it's probably not restrictive enough.

Comment: `window.location.toString().match(/[/ucp.php\?mode=register]/)`

Comment: Luca Kiebel i tried your answer but not executing the JS on all pages now.

Comment: Should've been `window.location.toString().match(/[ucp.php\?mode=register]/)`

Comment: Still not executing on all sites. The web is: exampledomain.com/ucp.php?mode=register -> its phpBB register form.